# Removing duplicates in R based on condition

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates

I need to embed a condition in a remove duplicates function. I am working with large student database from South Africa, a highly multilingual country. Last week you guys gave me the code to remove duplicates caused by retakes, but I now realise my language exam data shows some students offering more than 2 different languages.
The source data, simplified looks like this

```
STUDID   MATSUBJ     SCORE
101      AFRIKAANSB   1
101      AFRIKAANSB   4
102      ENGLISHB     2
102      ISIZULUB     7
102      ENGLISHB     5
```

The result file I need is

```
STUDID   MATSUBJ    SCORE  flagextra
101      AFRIKAANS   4
102      ENGLISH     5
102      ISIZULUB    7     1
```

I need to flag the extra language so that I can  see what languages they are and make new category for this

Comment: so extra language is the one which occurs just one time ?

Comment: Can you show some effort solving this problem? This is very similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964950/is-there-an-r-function-for-dropping-duplicates-of-index-variable-based-on-lowest) which has answers.

Comment: @PoGibas This my second question adds the complication of a condition to the earlier one about duplication. I have been using the answers to my first question, but hit a problem with the real data which requires this extra condition function

Answer (score 1):

Two stage procedure works better for me as a newbie to R:

1- remove the duplicates caused by subject retakes:

```
df <- LANGSEC%>%
     group_by(STUDID,MATRICSUBJ) %>%
     top_n(1,SUBJSCORE)
```

2- Then flag one of the two subjects causing the remaining duplicates:

```
LANGSEC$flagextra <- as.integer(duplicated(LANGSEC$STUDID),LANGSEC$MATRICSUBJ
```

Then filter for this third language and make new file:

```
LANG3<-LANGSEC%>% filter(flagextra==1)
```

Then remove these from the other file:

```
LANG2<-LANGSEC %>% filter(!flagextra==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(STUDID, MATSUBJ) %>% 
   summarise(SCORE = max(SCORE), 
             flagextra = as.integer(!sum(duplicated(MATSUBJ))))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   STUDID [?]
#  STUDID MATSUBJ    SCORE flagextra
#   <int> <chr>      <dbl>     <int>
#1    101 AFRIKAANSB     4         0
#2    102 ENGLISHB       5         0
#3    102 ISIZULUB       7         1
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
i1 <- !(duplicated(df1[1:2])|duplicated(df1[1:2], fromLast = TRUE))
transform(aggregate(SCORE ~ ., df1, max), 
          flagextra = as.integer(MATSUBJ %in% df1$MATSUBJ[i1]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(STUDID = c(101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L), MATSUBJ 
      = c("AFRIKAANSB", 
 "AFRIKAANSB", "ENGLISHB", "ISIZULUB", "ENGLISHB"), SCORE = c(1L, 
 4L, 2L, 7L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
 ))
```

Comment: Am still getting errors when try on real data as below (NB Lang2=MATSUBJ . L2score=score)

Comment: @CharlotteM  Without the error messages, it is not clear what the issue

Comment: LANG2 %>% group_by (STUDID,Lang2) %>% summarise(L2score=max(L2score),flagextra-as.integer(!sum(duplicated(Lang2))))
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors.

Comment: i1<-!(duplicated (LANG2[1:2]|duplicated (LANG2[1:2],fromLast=TRUE))transform (aggregate (L2score~.,LANG2,max),flagextra=as.integer(Lang2 %>% LANG2$Lang2 [i1]))
Error: unexpected symbol in "i1<-!(duplicated (LANG2[1:2]|duplicated (LANG2[1:2],fromLast=TRUE))transform"

Comment: @CharlotteM  The error is pretty much clear.  You have a `factor` column.  Based on the input showed, I assume it as `numeric`.  You may need to convert it to `numeric` first i.e. `LANG2$L2score <- as.numeric(as.character(LANG2$L2score))`

Comment: It is showing some unexpected symbol.  Perhaps you have submitted the code with the R console `>` symbol as well